# LCD is not printing strings, only integers with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, arduino-ide, lcd

As mentioned in the title I'm facing a problem in printing strings in the LCD. It's printing actually weird characters.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  lcd.print("hello, world!"); 
}
void loop() {


 lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(millis()/500);
}
```

You can find the output of the LCD in the picture below:

[image: LCD error !!]

Comment: You've goofed up the hardware side.

Comment: Agreed - it certainly hasn't initialized properly - it's in 16x1 mode not 16x2 mode, which means the 16x2 instruction never got through, so most likely you have your data lines in the wrong order.

Comment: And that looks like some pretty shoddy soldering. That's a good example of *go home and do it again*.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I use an LCD display I make sure to use the I2C backpack.  It takes actual effort to hook it up wrong if you use them.  So if this were me, I would desolder all those pins and get one.

Here is a good description of how they work:
https://learn.adafruit.com/i2c-spi-lcd-backpack/overview

Comment: Exactly my thought. It is possible to do the wiring and protocol yourself, but it will require a lot of pins and probably cause you some headaches.